# Store ObjectId instead of full object

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I Store ChatRoom with only the **SiteId** instance of full object ? 
thanks

```
  public class ChatRoom
 {
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public **Site** **Site** { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the party! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty straightforward if you're willing to change the model:

```
public class ChatRoom
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public ObjectId SiteId { get; set; }
}
```

However, that means that you need to *ensure referential integrity* yourself. For instance, if the `Site` you want to refer to hasn't been stored yet, you will first have to store the `Site` in the database, then store the `ChatRoom` with the `SiteId` set to the `Id` of the referenced `Site` - otherwise, there's no `Id` to refer to.

More importantly, that means you're no longer working with an object graph, or [domain model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) in your code. This has impact on your entire code architecture.

For example, you can't build expressions like `MyUser.ChatRoom.Site.Owner.Address.Street`. That has disadvantages, because you effectively can't implement a domain model at all, but it also comes with advantages because it's unclear when the freight trains actually would talk to the database.

However, these 'freight trains' are often dangerous, because it's unclear when the respective elements are loaded from the database.